# Magento 1.7 performance seems abnormally slow on WebFaction 512MB. (Nginx + PHP-FPM)

Tags: magento, nginx, php, webfaction, performance

I'm trying to move a Magento 1.7 site to a WebFaction 512MB plan. Currently it's on a several-GB Linode (and it absolutely rocks), but we have to move it onto our own server now and I'm having trouble getting it to perform well (typical page load is anywhere from 45s to several minutes, often timing out at 5 mins).

As mentioned in the title, I'm running Nginx with fastcgi_pass to the PHP-FPM socket (php 5.5.0, w/zend opcode). FWIW, I've already moved our Wordpress site to this server, and it's performing great under basically the same setup. I've also got a similar setup running on my local VM, similar PHP settings, and it doesn't have any trouble delivering a page in 3-5s. I've done lots of profiling with XDebug, and I'm still at a loss - it says that about 90% of the time is spent in spl_autoload (handled by lib/Varien/Autoload), but I don't know if there's anything I can actually do about that. I've echoed `get_include_path()` and it doesn't include anything weird, so... I just don't know.

Here's some relevant config info, at pastebin:

- [Nginx config](http://pastebin.com/hXrH1p6h)
- [php-fpm.conf](http://pastebin.com/ejZCvKGm)
- [php.ini](http://pastebin.com/kzeqUSwj)

I'm at my wits end, and am basically hoping for at the very least, a simple sanity check: Magento on Webfaction, 512MB, PHP Fastcgi - is that crazy? Not sure if it matters, but we've only got like 75 products. Let me know if there's other info that might help, I've got the php "slow logs", xdebug... yeah. I'm just unable to see the problem at this point, but I feel like I've got the tools to ferret it out, whatever it might be. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this will come down to the underpowered environment. Correct me if I am wrong but your hosting is probably a VPS and sometimes, no matter how much optimisation you do - it's often easier to upgrade the hosting.

Comment: WebFaction does this uniquely-awesome type of shared hosting, but it's not a VPS service, per se. What's your experience with this amount of memory though, 512MB - what kind of RAM would you suggest for a fairly low-traffic Magento site (we see maybe 5-10K/mo during peak sales season, 2-4K during slow season)? Thanks much for the advice though on upgrading, I'm hoping to avoid that if possible. We'll see though - it's not a terrible expense, I'm just not convinced that I don't have other issues lurking somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm at a loss why you would move from a VPS to a shared hosting provider like Webfaction.   If you bought a dedicated webfaction server why are you limited to only 512mb?

Comment: There's reasons. Like the fact that it isn't our box, and the owners aren't as security-conscious as I think they should be. Also, they charge us $25/mo for the hosting, which is shared by... about 100 other sites, some running osCommerce. (I know this because they accidentally gave me SSH access to the whole box). Also, we've got a WP site on our own server, and we want visitors to have a unified experience between WP & Magento, whereas currently they basically see 2 separate sites, on 2 separate servers. Very confusing. As for the plan, it's not dedicated, and we can buy more RAM.

Comment: I actually moved from Webfaction to Linode due to the fact that Webfaction had my site with a ton of other accounts.  my site would crawl several times a week.  I moved to a VPS with Linode where I have a dedicated amount of resources and I've had no problems running six django applications from one plan.   Webfaction has great customer support but I cannot build a business website with unreliable service.

Comment: Ha, well that's crappy news! :) And indeed, my problem is resolved now, it turns out that the issue was with the server I'm on, and they've since resolved that, now the site is back to normal, loads in 2-3s max, and that's with WP & Magento unified as one app - so it's not my code or my PHP settings or anything like that at all - it was the server. As for moving (again), I'll just have to see what the future holds. Linode is a pretty fine VPS service though, I've used them before, & would do so again.

Comment: yeah good luck with it.  I used webfaction for years.  I still think they are a great shared hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with my app or my nginx/php settings at all, it turns out the server my account is on was totally overloaded and has since been dealt with. My app now loads really fast, basically as you would expect.